# How to "dotnet pack" an already compiled project

Tags: .net, msbuild, .net-core, nuget, dotnet-cli

I'm trying to design a build script for a dotnet core 2.0 project that does the following actions

1. Cleans output directories
2. Builds Solution with -o bin\Publish
3. Runs Unit Tests with dotnet vstest
4. Creates a Nuget package with dotnet pack

Because I know the source code has been built and tested in steps 1-3 I do not want to rebuild my code for the nuget package, so I am specifying --no-build and --no-restore

The difficulty I'm having is that when creating the package, because I am not building and the output directory is set to be bin\Publish - the pack command is looking for items in the bin\Debug directory.

Is there a way I can set the dotnet pack command to *know* where to look for the already compiled objects?

Here is a sample of my build script

```
dotnet clean ..\MySolution.sln -o bin/Publish/
dotnet build ..\MySolution.sln /p:Configuration=Release -o bin/Publish/
dotnet vstest ..\MySolution.UnitTests\bin\Publish\MySolution.UnitTests.dll
dotnet pack --no-build --no-restore ..\MySolution.ConsoleApp\MySolution.csproj -o bin\Publish\Nuget\

....

error : The file 'D:\MySolution.ConsoleApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\MySolution.ConsoleApp.runtimeconfig.json' to be packed was not found on disk
```

According to the [Microsoft Docs on dotnet pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack?tabs=netcore2x)

> "By default, dotnet pack builds the project first. If you wish to
>   avoid this behavior, pass the --no-build option. This is often useful
>   in Continuous Integration (CI) build scenarios where you know the code
>   was previously built."

So I'm hoping that this is possible and I'm missing something obvious. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The reason for this is that the `dotnet pack --no-build` option will try to use the previously built output, but can't find it since you built to a non-standard output path and the pack logic needs to locate some assets generated into the build output.

The `-o` options are internally different for the `pack` and `build` commands but you can change the pack command to:

```
dotnet pack --no-build --no-restore ..\MySolution.ConsoleApp\MySolution.csproj -o bin\Publish\Nuget\ /p:OutputPath=bin\Publish\
```

This will use the output built into the `bin\Publish` directory and put it into the Nuget output directory in `bin\Publish\Nuget\`

Comment: I was just about there - I had only had the thought to override the MSBuild internal parameters just as you commented - thank you for your answer!

Comment: ``--no-build`` will also implicitly sets ``--no-restore`` (as per documentation)

Comment: Yes this was "fixed" in 2.1/2.2, do note that this question originally was about 2.0 which didn't yet do this - https://github.com/dotnet/cli/pull/8100 (which is why I deliberately listed both in the answer)

Comment: Hello. I tried this solution and it worked up to a specific point, here meaning that the content of the Nuget package is all scrambled and not all dependencies are included. Does anyone have an idea why? Or how should I do it to include the exact contents and structure of the \Publish folder?

Comment: nuget packages with `dotnet pack` only contain the own build output, not any of dependencies (those are included as NuGet dependencies, so you get a .nupkg for each csproj). If you build tools, you can build tool packages instead [tutorial doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools-how-to-create)