# How do I stop dotnet pack building the project in azure devops (--no-build doesnt have an effect)

Tags: .net, azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, dotnet-cli

I am having issues creating a nuget package from a project in azure devops, The project is .net standard 2.0 targeting `netstandard2.0` and `netcoreapp2.0`.

I have a separate build and release pipelines.

The build pipeline builds & tests the project.

The release pipeline takes the output from the build and runs `dotnet pack` on it. However it is trying to do a build at the same time (which fails).

The documentation that I have seen suggests that adding `--no-build` when calling nuget pack should make it use the existing dlls from the bin directory.

I have been through the logs and this is the command that devops has been running (I have removed some identifying information) : 
`pack E:\Agents\build1\r82\a\...\MyProject.csproj --output E:\Agents\build1\r82\a\...\packages --no-build /p:Configuration=Release --verbosity Detailed`

This does a build which then fails with a message that some referenced nuget packages could not be found.

I could just put a `dotnet restore` in there and let it do the build but I don't see why we would need to do that given that the build pipeline has already created the dlls.

Note, I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232375/how-to-dotnet-pack-an-already-compiled-project) but in that instance the issue was that the build was output to a non-standard directory, that is not the case here.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: How did you define your release pipeline?

Answer (score 3):

It seems the argument `--no-build` is not working in `dotnet pack` of `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task. Please try to use `dotnet custom` as a workaround:

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet custom'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    projects: '**\*.csproj'
    custom: pack
    arguments: '--no-build'
```

Comment: dotnet pack also ignores the --configuration argument.  But this workaround seems to work...