# Packing nuget targeting net 4.8 from linux

Tags: .net-core, .net-4.8, dotnet-core-pack

I'm using a docker container to build a nuget package using

`dotnet pack ...`

The csproj is multi-targeted for
netstandard2.1 and net48.

Obviously I get an error that the targeting pack for net48 is missing.

Given that a nuget is just a packge of the dll's is it possible somehow to pack a nuget targeted for net 48 from a Linux docker ?
Or do I have to use windows for this ?

Comment: You can create a nuget package, provided you had the net48.dll already compiled. You can not compile net48 binaries on linux. `dotnet pack` will compile your project and _then_ package it into a nuget package, so this will not work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232375/how-to-dotnet-pack-an-already-compiled-project